# Read class data from object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a class named Document `DocumentViewer` in my selenium project which contains method named `CancelAndClose` and it returns an object. This method is accessed by four different objects. So the main idea behind using this `method` is to return the exact type of `object`(with a parameter) that called this `method`.

Here is the body of `DocumentViewer` class:

```
public class DocumentViewer
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    private object _startedFrom;

    public DocumentViewer(IWebDriver driver, object startedFrom)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        _startedFrom = startedFrom;
        //CODE TO CHECK WHETHER IS DRIVER IS IN THE RIGHT PAGE
        }
    }

    public object CancelAndClose()
    {
        //I USE A CUSTOM METHOD FOR FINDING THE RIGHT WINDOW HANDLE AND RETURN IT BELOW
        return new OneOfTheFourClasses(_driver);
    }
}
```

So my question is, how do I find the original class of the object `_startedFrom` and set it in the place of `OneOfTheFourClasses` ?

EDIT: This `DocumentViewer` is a page object and also `TheFourClasses` as well.

Comment: Use a common base interface.

Comment: Are you attempting to implement a Page Object model here? Don't pass around `objects`, create classes and controls that give semantic meaning. You won't have to do all the reflection nonsense then. I should *know* what the object type is *just from looking at it in code*.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I am looking at options here. I don't want to implement bad code. And yeah reflection and all is not readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: I don't know / haven't used Selenium so I have no idea if what you're trying to do is "proper" (or sane, etc.) or not, but I can literally answer your question...*

To find out its type, you can simply call `_startedFrom.GetType()`.

To construct another object of the same type, you need to use reflection.

```
var type = _startedFrom.GetType();
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IWebDriver) });
var newObject = ctor.Invoke( new object[] { _driver } );
```

Comment: So now all I have to do is just return the newObject ?

Comment: @VenkatapathiRajuM Theoretically yes. But I'm afraid to say too much because, having never used Selenium, I don't know what the right thing to return is. All I can say is that `newObject` at this point is a constructed, ready-to-use object of the same type as `_startedFrom` (assuming that type has a constructor that takes a single argument of type `IWebDriver`, which I inferred from the rest of your code).

Comment: Yes that type has a constructor which takes in IWebDriver.

Comment: This code has not much to do with selenium. As it is a framework that is a layer above Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use [GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public DocumentViewer(IWebDriver driver, object startedFrom)
{
    _driver = driver;
    _startedFrom = startedFrom;

    //CODE TO CHECK WHETHER IS DRIVER IS IN THE RIGHT PAGE
    Type objectType = _startedFrom.GetType();
}
```

Comment: I tried using GetType(). But didn't know how to create a new instance of that class using GetType and pass in this parameter.

Comment: @dvnrrs has that in his answer